# How to add multiple timer to a thread

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I'm trying to add multiple timers to a thread, not the main thread.Here is code:

```
- (IBAction)addTimer:(id)sender 
{
  if (!_timerQueue) {
    _timerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("timer_queue", NULL);
  }

  dispatch_async(_timerQueue, ^{
    NSTimer *tempTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:tempTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
  });
}
```

The method above is triggered by a button action. But the code in the dispatch block runs only once not matter how many times i click the button. So only one Timer in that thread.  I wonder why?

Comment: + scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval ... family will return the timer that already scheduled on the current runloop so you must first give them a runloop or use the 
+ timerWithTimeInterval ... as in 
   
   

`NSTimer *tempTimer = [NSTimer timerTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:tempTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];`

Comment: You're way over-complicating things. Why use a thread? You can schedule your timers on the main thread and then dispatch expensive operations to background as necessary. If you really want a thread, don't use GCD. Just create a thread with `NSThread` put a source, like an `NSPort`, in its run loop so it doesn't exit, and run the run loop. Then, use `-performSelector:onThread:...` to add timers to it.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, Ken. I solved the problem by add some dispatch timer sources to that dispatch thread. Actually I learn little about NSThread. From the videos I watch so far, they seen to use GCD more often. I just think GCD and NSThread are doing pretty much the same thing...

Comment: Let me chime in here: "GCD and NSThread are doing pretty much the same thing". Well, no. `NSThread` is an Objective-C wrapper around raw POSIX threads. If you instantiate an `NSThread` you are guaranteed to create one POSIX thread. If you create a GCD-queue you…do something else that will result in the creation of _any number_ (including zero!) of POSIX threads to which your work items (in the form of dispatch blocks) can be submitted in the order they were scheduled. GCD manages a _pool_ of threads based on criteria such as overall system load and number of enqueued work items.

Comment: Sequel: A major implication of the "fire and forget" semantic of GCD is the phenomenon you've just encountered: The work items _themselves_ need to be atomic. Especially, they must be _finite_ in the sense that they have a well defined intrinsic end. Prime examples are computation tasks like analyzing a dataset (or a subset of some large dataset) or parsing a file. Timers — especially repeating ones — and other event-driven tasks do not fit into this scheme at all. Whether or not a timer is "finished" usually depends on external parameters only.

Comment: So if I just need a timer, it would be better to use NSThread. Ah~ Seens I need to learn more about these thread things, especially NSThread. Thank you danyowdee again for explaining all these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you only see one timer at a time is in the last line of your dispatch block:

`-[NSRunLoop run]` is a blocking call that returns when the last input source of the run loop finishes and no timers are scheduled anymore.

In addition, GCD-queues are strictly FIFO and you are creating a serial queue.
Thus, the result of you tapping that button several times is a queue that gets fuller and fuller without the first block ever finishing:
Since the timer is repeating, there always is something scheduled on the run loop and thus `run` never returns, barring all subsequent blocks from ever being invoked.

Comment: Oh, I see. That explains those "weird" things. Thank you danyowdee.